# Can I pass a list of objects into a session? Django/Python

Tags: python, django, session

I have data that does not need stored in a db. I have a list of results from an API that is made up of objects i created based off of what is returned by the api. I want to display results in an html table. When I paginate i lose all that data and want to pass the list of objects into the session to pass with each page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything which can be serialized in the session. It's possible that you will have to restructure your "objects" or store the same data as dicts and lists.

Try it and see?

Comment: Nigel! Thank you. This is one of those situations where i completely over thought things! I tried, and boom we got it working.